# how to put quote inside a quote javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a problem when I try to render out a table cell after a successful ajax call.

How can I put an `id` in function `deleteServiceIdFromInput()`?

I tried:

```
deleteServiceIdFromInput('"+ id +"');
```

I also tried adding `\" \"`, but it still didn't work.
Any suggestion would be great, thanks.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "./OTTProductMapServIDAjaxSubmit.do",
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {"productID":productID,"serviceID":serviceID, "method":"searchSerivceById"},
          success: function(data){

            document.getElementById("listOfServiceID").value;
            if (data != null){
            var table = document.getElementById("serviceMappingTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(1);
            row.align="center";
            row.onmouseover = function(){this.bgColor = '#C0C0C0';};
            row.onmouseout = function(){this.bgColor = '#FFFFFF';};

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);



            cell1.innerHTML= '<a href="javascript:deleteServiceIdFromInput('"+ id +"')" class="cssBtn">Delete</a>';
            insertServiceIdToInput(data.serv_id);

        }
```

the end result I am looking for as it will rendered in HTML as (below) :

```
href="javascript:deleteServiceIdFromInput(' id ')"
```

and for solution i have tried, redered in HTML as :

```
href="javascript:deleteServiceIdFromInput( id )"  <-- quote is missing
```

Comment: Providing the expected output would be very useful

Comment: If you just want to append the variable id then write the following code
cell1.innerHTML= '<a href="javascript:deleteServiceIdFromInput('+ id +')" class="cssBtn">Delete</a>';

Comment: hey Nakarmi thank you for helping, but thats is not i am looking for, what i am looking for ? (i edited the question above), as i have tried your solution  i got <a href="javascript:deleteServiceIdFromInput(XA0001)" (the quote is still missing in HTML as rendered),,error in chrome (Uncaught ReferenceError: XQ0001 is not defined) ,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
cell1.innerHTML= '<a href="javascript:deleteServiceIdFromInput("'+ id +'") class="cssBtn">Delete</a>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, why not use the [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function?

I tested with this following code and it works:

HTML:

```
<div id='cell1'></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var id = '123';
var htmlContent = "<a href=\"javascript:deleteServiceIdFromInput('" 
                + id 
                + "')\" class=\"cssBtn\">Delete</a>";

$('#cell1').html(htmlContent);
```

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nkwn390u/

Answer (score 0):

This works, Thank you all for helping !

```
cell1.innerHTML= '<a href="javascript:deleteServiceIdFromInput(\''+ id +'\')" class="cssBtn">Delete</a>'
```